# Is it true that there were "wooden guiding structures" proposed, by the ancient Greek, to account for the motions of the planets?

Tags: astronomy, ancient-greece

I can remember after attending a philosophy of science class, I put forward the thought ancient Greek had about the motion of the planets. I had read about them thinking there are wooden circular structures placed on the heavenly sphere in which the planets are guided. Like a train on a rail.

I am sure I read it, which is the reason I brought it up. I cant find anything about it and I cant remember where I read it. Maybe the book on the history of astronomy by Dyksterhuis.

Comment: This is a pretty silly question, if it is a question at all.  At the very least  you should have reread Dijksterhuis's book before posting.

Comment: @kimchilover I dont have the book anymore and I dont say its in there for sure. I only say it might be in there because I made an essay about the history of astronomy and used his book for this. At the same time there was a philosophy class in which I mentioned this. So your comment is the silly one.